# Add a class to selected div that compares input value and data function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created two 'button' boxes that will act as a way to change a hidden radio input.

When you click on the 'Option 1' box, it will update the selected field of the radio input. What I need it to do now, is add a class to the clicked `.nc-option` if the value of the radio box is equal.

I've tried to say `if` the `#campaign_select input` has the same value as the clicked data-function value, then add `.active` - but can't seem to figure it out.

PS: I am using WordPress ACF, hence reason I am not just adding content inside radio area.

[**Fiddle Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/kps46ojv/3/)

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", "[id^=choice]", function() {

  if ($("#campaign_select input").val() == $(this).data("function")) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  }
  var no = this.id.replace("choice", "");
  $("#campaign_select input[value=" + no + "]").click().prop("checked", true);

});
```

```css
.nc-type {
  background: #1b2836;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8rem 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nc-type p {
  color: #8899A6;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.nc-type h3 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.page-template-page-submit .page-body-inner {
  border-top: 0;
}

#campaign_select .acf-radio-list {
  display: block;
}

.nc-option {
  background: #243447;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.nc-option label {
  color: #fff;
}

.nc-option:hover {
  background: #2c3f56;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nc-option svg {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}

.nc-option p {
  color: #8899A6;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

.nc-option-1 .a {
  fill: #1DA1F2;
}

.nc-option-2 .a {
  fill: #f2771d;
}

.nc-option-3 .a {
  fill: #1df27f;
}

.nc-option-4 .a {
  fill: #f21d90;
}

.active {
  border-color: #1da1f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nc-campaign-select">
  <div id="choice1" class="nc-option nc-option-1" data-function="1">
    <label>Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <!-- end of option -->
  <div id="choice2" class="nc-option nc-option-2" data-function="2">
    <label>Option 2</label>
  </div>
  <!-- end of option -->
</div>

<div id="campaign_select">
  <div class="acf-input">
    <input type="hidden">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label class="selected">
          <input type="radio" id="ac-1" name="ac" value="1" checked="checked">Option 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="">
          <input type="radio" id="ac-2" name="ac" value="2">Option 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. You don't need to check if the two values are equal. Just remove `.active` class if it is already added to any button box and add it to the one that is currently clicked.
JS:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "[id^=choice]", function(event) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $("[id^=choice]").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var no = this.id.replace("choice", "");
    jQuery("#campaign_select input[value=" + no + "]").prop("checked", true);
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nc-campaign-select">
  <div id="choice1" class="nc-option nc-option-1 active" data-function="1">
    <label>Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <!-- end of option -->
  <div id="choice2" class="nc-option nc-option-2" data-function="2">
    <label>Option 2</label>
  </div>
  <!-- end of option -->
</div>

<div id="campaign_select">
  <div class="acf-input">
    <input type="hidden">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label class="selected">
          <input type="radio" id="ac-1" name="ac" value="1" checked="checked">Option 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="">
          <input type="radio" id="ac-2" name="ac" value="2">Option 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That done the trick! Didn't think about only checking if it has the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is not right. You have to remove class first and then add class to the current div

***Stack Snippet***

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", "[id^=choice]", function() {
  var no = this.id.replace("choice", "");
  if ($(this).data("function") == no) {
    $('.nc-option').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  } else {}
  jQuery("#campaign_select input[value=" + no + "]").click().prop("checked", true);
});
```

```css
.nc-type {
  background: $branding_2;
  border: 1px solid $branding_3;
  padding: 8rem 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.nc-option {
  background: #243447;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid $branding_3;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.active {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nc-campaign-select">
  <div id="choice1" class="nc-option nc-option-1" data-function="1">
    <label>Option 1</label>
  </div>
  <!-- end of option -->
  <div id="choice2" class="nc-option nc-option-2" data-function="2">
    <label>Option 2</label>
  </div>
  <!-- end of option -->
</div>

<div id="campaign_select">
  <div class="acf-input">
    <input type="hidden">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label class="selected">
          <input type="radio" id="ac-1" name="ac" value="1" checked="checked">Option 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="">
          <input type="radio" id="ac-2" name="ac" value="2">Option 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/kps46ojv/4/)**